# How to check if server is down or not existent in python telnet?

Tags: python, telnetlib

I'm trying to loop through some PDU servers to check entries are following our naming conventions.

I'm writing a python script to check all these servers.  However, I'm running into a problem where if the server is down, it makes my script error out and fail.

I don't know how to deal with the gaierror I'm getting on some servers that are unreachable or non-existent.  I thought I handled it in the "finally" block but apparently not.

Here's my code.

```
try:
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet()
    tn.open(pdu_host)
    print(tn.read_until(b'Username: '))
    tn.write(PDU_USER + b"\n")
    print(tn.read_until(b'Password: '))
    tn.write(PDU_PASSWORD + b"\n")
    _, _, data = tn.expect([br'Switched .DU:'])
finally:
    # close the connection
    if tn is not None:
        tn.write(b'logout\n')
        print(tn.read_all())
        tn.close()
        print ('logged out')
        time.sleep(2)  # give the connection time to close
```

It seems like when I get a gaierror, tn is not None and still tries to run the commands in the finally block, which makes my script fail.  When I manually try to telnet to the server, it says:

```
could not resolve serverX/telnet: Name or service not known
```

How do I handle this error case when my existing code didn't handle it?

EDIT: This is the error I'm getting when running my script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_pdu_outlets.py", line 58, in <module>
    tn.write(b'logout\n')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 283, in write
    self.sock.sendall(buffer)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
```

When I run the script thru pdb and I step through the code line by line, it says I get the gaierror when it tries to open a non-existent or down server

```
-> tn.open(pdu_host)
(Pdb) n
gaierror: (-2, 'Name or service not known')
```

Comment: Could you include the full error?

Comment: @PacketLoss, thanks for looking at my question.  I've updated it with the error message I get

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to resolve this is to change your `if statement` in `finally()` to check if an open socket exists for the connection.

```
if tn.get_socket():
```

If no connection is open, it will return `None`

Example

---

```
from telnetlib import Telnet

tn = Telnet()

print(type(tn.get_socket()))
#<class 'NoneType'>

tn.open('192.168.0.1')

tn.get_socket()
#<socket.socket fd=764, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.1.1', 54489), raddr=('192.168.0.1', 23)>

tn.close()

print(type(tn.get_socket()))
#<class 'NoneType'>
```

From `telnetlib.py`:

```
def get_socket(self):
        """Return the socket object used internally."""
        return self.sock
```

Comment: I still get a Traceback when I use what you suggested BUT because of your suggestion, I am doing a socket.gethostbyname(pdu_host) check in the try block which seems to make my script work  :)  Upvote for pointing me in this direction to find a solution  :)

Comment: @Classified You could also check if the socket exists immediately after opening the connection. If it exists, do what you need to do. If not continue looping to the next one.